# Is QueryUnbiasedInterruptTime monotonic?

Tags: windows, winapi, time, timer

I'm trying to find a decent replacement on Windows for `clock_gettime(CLOCK_MONOTONIC)` and `mach_absolute_time`.

`GetTickCount` is annoying because it's deliberately biased: when the system resumes from suspend or hibernation, it seems Windows works out how long it was suspended (from motherboard) then adds that to the tick count to make it look like the tick carried on while the system was powered down.

`QueryUnbiasedInterruptTime` is friendlier: it's a simple, seemingly-reliable counter that just returns the time the system has been running since boot.

Now, I've experimented with `QueryUnbiasedInterruptTime` to see what happens when the computer enters each of: sleep, hybrid sleep, and hibernation. It appears that it's correctly updated so that it appears to be monotonic (ie, the system stashes it before hibernation and restores it so that applications aren't confused).

But, there's a note [here on the Python dev pages](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0418/#sleep) (which, by the way, are a very helpful resource for time function reference!):

> QueryUnbiasedInterruptTime() is not monotonic.

I presume someone did a test to determine that. Is that information accurate? If so, out of interest I wonder what you have to do to get the return value to go backwards.

Comment: My money is on them confusing monotonic with continuous.  It is not, the update rate is unpredictable.  Fire up Chrome and it suddenly starts incrementing with 1 msec precision.  Getting apps to stop abusing timeBeginPeriod() is going to take a while.

Comment: Hmm, that would be a bit surprising, since it's used correctly elsewhere in the article, which collects together a lot of helpful platform-specific information.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`QueryUnbiasedInterruptTime` is guaranteed to be monotonic. The interrupt time has no skew added to it, so it always ticks forward although the rate may sometimes differ a little from the wall clock.

I couldn't find any good references for this in MSDN, but I'm now convinced that Hans is right in his comment, the CPython developers must have simply got confused.

Comment: Re MSDN reference, the primary article says [... begins at zero... and is incremented at...](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/realtimeapiset/nf-realtimeapiset-queryunbiasedinterrupttime#remarks), which sounds like a guarantee for being monotonic.

Answer (score 0):

The main problem with GetTickCount is the value being only 32 bits, i.e. it resets to zero every 50 days of uptime.

You probably need `QueryPerformanceCounter` API.

Comment: Take another look at the question title.

Comment: Take another look at the question 1st sentence. Both mach_absolute_time and clock_gettime(CLOCK_MONOTONIC) are high-resolution timers, while QueryUnbiasedInterruptTime only updates 64 times per second (unless some app mess with timeBeginPeriod API, but even in this case `QueryPerformanceCounter` is much more precise).