# Accurate time delta for moderate time intervals: GetTickCount64 vs QueryPerformanceCounter

Tags: windows, time, performancecounter

There are lots of questions ([here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38588121), [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21115082), [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44020619)) about mechanisms for getting monotonic time on Windows and their various gotchas and pitfalls. I'm particularly interested in the accuracy (not precision) of the main options.

I'm looking to measure elapsed time on a single machine, when the time is on the order of multiple minutes to an hour. What i know so far:

- [QueryPerformanceCounter](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms644904(v=vs.85).aspx) is great for short time intervals, but QPF can have error on the order of 500PPM, which translates to error of 2 seconds over an hour.

  - More concerning is that even on fairly recent processors, [folks are seeing QPC misbehavior](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44020619).
  - Microsoft recommends QPC above all else for short-term duration measurements. But short-term isn't defined in any absolute numbers.
- [GetTickCount64](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms724411(v=vs.85).aspx) is often cited as a nice and reliable, less precise alternative for QPC.

  - I've not found any good details about the accuracy of GetTickCount64. While it is less precise than QPC, how does its accuracy compare? What kind of error might I expect over an hour?
  - Some programs play with its resolution by using [timeBeginPeriod](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/dd757624(v=vs.85).aspx), although I don't think this affects accuracy?
  - The docs talk about how GetTickCount64's resolution is not affected by adjustments made by the [GetSystemTimeAdjustment](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms724394(v=vs.85).aspx) function. Hopefully this means GetTickCount64 is monotonic and not adjusted ever? It is unusual wording...
- [GetSystemTimePreciseAsFileTime](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/hh706895(v=vs.85).aspx) is an option for same-machine time deltas if I disable automatic time adjustment via [SetSystemTimeAdjustment](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms724943(v=vs.85).aspx). It is backed by QPC. Is there any benefit to using this over QPC directly? (Perhaps it does sanitization or thread affinity tricks to avoid some of the issues encountered by direct QPC calls?)

Comment: I think the biggest piece I am missing to answer my question is what serves as the time source for GetTickCount64? I don't see it called out anywhere. The docs talk about how the system provides an interrupt based on the default period or whatever is specified via timeBeginPeriod, but not what time source is used to provide that interrupt.

Comment: The time source for GetTickCount is the system timer, with a resolution of normally 15.6ms these days (1/64th of a second), but this can be changed with the multimedia timer functions. It is very steady, but has very low precision (1ms is the lowest you can set the timer resolution with documented APIs). GetTickCount64 is just an extension to GetTickCount to avoid overflowing every few weeks.

Comment: Windows 10 also adds QueryInterruptTime and QueryInterruptTimePrecise which use the same time source (mincore.lib for import library, but they're in kernel32.dll). QueryInterruptTime has the same observable granularity as GetTickCount, but 100ns precision; QueryInterruptTimePrecise has 100ns precision and uses QPC to increase granularity for shorter time scales (probably the most similar Windows time source to CLOCK_BOOTTIME on Linux or CLOCK_MONOTONIC on BSDs)

Answer (score 1):

One SO QA I found [linked to this blog post](https://aakinshin.net/blog/post/stopwatch/), which has been particularly useful to read. While it doesn't answer my question directly, it dives into how QPC works on Windows, and how the common linux monotonic time basically uses the same thing.

The gist is that both of them use `rtdsc` when an invariant TSC on modern hardware is available.